# Проблема с NetBeans и не могу добавить иконку в jLabel!

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jar

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.net.URL.toExternalForm()" because "location" is null - вот ошибка. Cтруктура проекта : [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Строка в которой что-то не так : jLabel_close.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("com/img/user.png")));
Пробывал варианты с PNG,../ и др. - не помогают!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё оказалось куда прозаичнее - я доставал картинки из путей как относительных так и абсолютных, не уверен что до конца разбираюсь в чём их разница, но пути C:/Пользователи/User/Папка/Подпапка/ и т.д. "ругались", потому что моя папка **Пользователи** так и называется и отображается и используется как **Пользователи**, а не **Users**!(хотя в свойствах(Alt+Enter) папки отображается **Users**,а если просто из проводника смотреть то **Пользователи**) Решил проблему доставать картинки прямо из корня диска C :)(т.е. `jLabel_close.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("C:/image.png"));`),ибо это мне не вредило , т.к. не требовался запуск программы с других ПК.